# How to store and list Ionic 3 array by firebase

Tags: arrays, firebase, ionic3

I want to store the following data in Firebase and use the same in Ionic 3 but I did not find any clear documentation that could help me. Can someone give me a way?

This is an example of array on `home.ts`

```
initializeItems() {
   this.items = [
     {id: '1', nome:'Abaéte', rua:'Moacir', cidade:'Capão da Canoa', bairro:'Centro', numero:'396', ano:'1964', aptos:'55', adm:'Adsel', zelador:'Hugo', contato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', imagem:'assets/img/Abaete-min.jpg'},
   ];
```

And this a image the App list

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your sample shows an `object` not an `array`. Yes you can push `objects` to Firebase.

I'm assuming you're using `angularfire2` with Ionic.

```
const myObject = {
  id: '1', 
  nome:'Abaéte', 
  rua:'Moacir', 
  cidade:'Capão da Canoa', 
  bairro:'Centro', 
  numero:'396', 
  ano:'1964', 
  aptos:'55', 
  adm:'Adsel', 
  zelador:'Hugo', c
  ontato1:'(51) 0 0000 - 0000', 
  contato2: '(51) 0000 - 0000', 
  imagem:'assets/img/5yDViHGwTkaJSEDkHyqS_Abaete.JPG'
}

this.db.list('/some/path').push(myObject)
  .then(resp => {
    console.log('All Saved!');
  });
```

If you do want to push arrays you should take a look at the [Firebase Blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). It discourages saving arrays, but instead using the `push` method to generate a unique ID for each array item.